# Autocomplete JQuery UI - tooltips will not display

Tags: c#, jquery, json

[image]

When I put view code to Home/Index.html I get the above effect. Tooltips will not display. What can I do to fix this?

Here is the code I have:

Script (productSuggest):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var setupAutoComplete = function () {
        var $input = $(this);

        var options = {
            source: $input.attr("data-autocomplete-source"),
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $input = $(this);
                $input.val(ui.item.label);
                var $form = $input.parents("form:first");
            }
        };
        $input.autocomplete(options);
    };
    $("#seatch-filter").each(setupAutoComplete);
});
```

_Layout:

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <form id="seatch-form">
                        <input id="seatch-filter" type="search" name="searchQuery"
                               data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("ProductsSuggestions")"
                               placeholder="Szukaj..." />
                        <input type="submit" value="" />
                    </form>
</div>
```

and HomeController action:

```
 public ActionResult ProductsSuggestions(string term)
        {
            var products = this.db.Product.Where(p => !p.IsHidden && p.ProductTitle.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()))
            .Take(5).Select(p => new { label = p.ProductTitle });
            return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Done,
problem was in controller action, because HomeController doesn't work with _Layout.cshtml.